# what is wrong with my understanding of strings ie character arrays ending with '\0' element in C programming

Tags: c, string

I am a total beginner and recently started studying strings in C programming.

I understand that we need to supply the `'\0'` (null) character at the end of the string (to act as a end of string marker).
So if my character array is

```
char string[]={'H','E','L','L','O','\0'};
```

This makes it a 6 element array.

So I was going through this simple example of copying one string to another string. Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    char string1[80],string2[80];
    int i;

    printf("Enter a string \n");
    gets(string2);

    for(i=0; string2[i]!= '\0';i++)
    {
        string1[i]=string2[i];

    }
    string1[i]='\0';  /*here is my problem*/
    printf("The copied string is \n");
    printf("%s",string1);
    printf("\n");
    printf("The number of character are \t");
    printf("%d \n",i);

}
```

why isn't it `string1[i+1]='\0'`??
I mean, isn't by putting `string1[i]='\0'` overwrite the last element that was just stored in the above for loop?

Comment: Nitpick: `'\0'` is `NUL` and `(void *)0` is `NULL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct, because of the way the `for` loop works:

```
for(A; B; C)
    CODE;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
A;
while (B)
{
    CODE;
    C;
}
```

(Except for the use of `continue`, that will jump to the increment expression, not the condition, as it would happen with a `while`).

And since the loop ends when `string2[i] != '\0'`, it is obvious that upon exiting, `i` is the index for the proper `NUL` byte. So after that:

```
string1[i] = '\0';
```

will write the `\0` at the same place as it is in `string2`.

---

Usually for this kind of analysis it is helpful to think about `preconditions` and `postconditions`. That is, assuming there are no `break` and no `goto`, you are guaranteed that at the beginning of a `for` or `while` loop the condition is always `true`. And just after the end of a `for` or `while` loop the condition is always `false`.

Your particular code, illustrated with `assert` calls:

```
for(i=0; string2[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    asssert(string2[i] != '\0');
    string1[i] = string2[i];
}
asssert(string2[i] == '\0');
string1[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: I have another similar looping doubt,shall I ask here or ask a new question?

Comment: @Halloworld: If it is about the same thing (output condition of a loop), it can be a comment, of the kind _request a clarification_. If not directly related to this, then it is better to do a new question.

Comment: Say,this example
`code
do
{
character=getchar();
string[i]=character;
c++;
}

while(character != '\n');
c=c-1;     /* Why is that? now shouldn't it just be c */
line[c]= '\0';
printf(" %s \n",string);
}
`

Comment: @Halloworld: Ah, but that `c = c -1;` is there probably because the author of this code wants to remove the ending `\n` from the string. BTW, IME it is better to use `break` and avoid wiggling with the indices: `for (;;) { character = getchar(); if (character == '\n') break; string[i++] = character; } string[i] = '\0';`.

Comment: Is there any place I can contact you?

Comment: @Halloworld: Sure! In my SO profile you will see a link to my blog. There there is an "About" page with my email address. It is hard to find so that only really interested people will reach it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, it seems as if i is incremented as long as the character is not '\0'.  So, the last time it's incremented, it increments to a new position that hasn't had a character written to it yet.

So, at the end of the loop, there's a space to write the null character to.